# Delete a 10000th node in linked list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, time-complexity, skip-lists

I have a linked list of n nodes , i want to delete a kth node and display the element in it. This is easy if the value of n is relatively small and complexity of the problem is not a issue.

The problem is when i have n nodes in the linked list where n >=200000 and i want to delete a node which is also a relatively great value (say k=150000).

The normal solution to this problem is traverse the whole linked list and delete a node (where the complexity of the solution is O(n) ), though it is straight forward and easy solution it takes more time. Other solution to this problem can be having 2 pointers but still that is not optimal solution.

I am looking for a solution which is optimal and provides result in minimal amount of time.

Hope my question is clear. Need some help..

Comment: Is this just an interview question or do you have a real world scenario? If later, can you give more insights on other things like what's under your control and what all can be changed ?

Comment: If you have a singly linked list, then your only choice is the O(n) solution. Are you allowed to modify the data structure to add more information? Like maintaining a list of references to intermediate nodes, as suggested by one of the answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**SkipList**](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/skip-list/) concept.

It is like using *Express* Lanes or Highway Roads, to reach to the desired node at the fastest possible speed (by choosing minimal traversal length).

You need to create multiple layers so that you can ***skip some nodes*** without any hesitation.

**TC:** Same average running time as Binary Search Tree `O(log n)`.

Doesn't requires complex reorganisation of the given linked list.

Answer (score 0):

You have a linked list so your access is O(n).. 
I see two choices : change your container or use a secondary container to speed up direct access (increase your space complexity)..
You won't find a magic container with O(1) complexity for all treatments.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but increasing space complexity is not a great option is what i felt unless there are no other ways of doing it.

Comment: Though not `O(1)`, but `O(log n)` can definitely be achieved by using the `skip-list`, which is substantial improvement over `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

In a standard linked list, there is no way (without additional pointers) to quickly access elements later in the list, since the only reference to said elements occurs in the element directly preceding it.

If you know that you will often need to access an element whose index is known, it is probably better to just use an array. (Though re-reading the question, this still isn't any good for deleting the element)

Comment: Thanks Matt for the solution. But i have a small doubt (though i feel it is stupid i want to clear it), suppose i have the address of the first node of the list , by using the this address and knowing the size of the each node  and doing some basic mathematical operation, can i know the address of kth node in linked list?

Comment: and access the element directly?

Comment: @sushh No you can't. That you can do only with containers which store elements in contiguous memory address. Lists are, unlike array, stored in non-continuous memory addresses. This is what makes the deletion operation easierand incredibly less costlier in lists, as you don't have to move the trailing element forward.

Comment: Not necessarily, since one of the benefits of a linked list is the fact that the nodes do not need to be in sequential order, meaning that in most cases there is no way of predicting the location of a particular node.

Comment: @SauravSahu and Matt thanks for the response. I realised why it cant be done.